# Read annotated data from GATE datastore

Tags: java, gate

I use GATE for manually annotating a large amount of texts by its contained emotions. To further process this text, I like to export that out of the datastore into my own Java application. I didn't found documentation about how to do that. I already wrote a program to import data into the datastore, but I don't have an idea how to get the annotated out of the datastore. I also tried to open the lucene based datastore using Luke (https://code.google.com/p/luke/). It's a tool, that is able to read a Lucene index. But it was not possible to open the Gate Lucene datastore using that tool :( Does anyone has an idea how to read the annotated text from the datastore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GATE APIs to load the documents from the datastore and then export them as GATE XML in the normal way (imports and exception handling omitted):

```
Gate.init();
DataStore ds = Factory.openDataStore("gate.creole.annic.SearchableDataStore", "file:/path/to/datastore");
List docIds = ds.getLrIds("gate.corpora.DocumentImpl");
for(Object id : docIds) {
  Document d = (Document)Factory.createResource("gate.corpora.DocumentImpl",
            gate.Utils.featureMap(DataStore.DATASTORE_FEATURE_NAME, ds,
                                  DataStore.LR_ID_FEATURE_NAME, id));
  try {
    File outputFile = new File(...); // based on doc name, sequential number, etc.
    DocumentStaxUtils.writeDocument(d, outputFile);
  } finally {
    Factory.deleteResource(d);
  }
}
```

If you want to write the annotations as inline XML then replace `DocumentStaxUtils.writeDocument` with something like

```
Set<String> types = new HashSet<String>();
types.add("Person");
types.add("Location"); // and whatever others you're interested in
FileUtils.write(outputFile, d.toXml(d.getAnnotations().get(types), true));
```

(I'm using [FileUtils from Apache commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) for convenience but you could equally handle opening and closing the file yourself).

Comment: cool! Thanks for the fast answer. I had to change gate.creole.annic.SearchableDataStore to gate.persist.LuceneDataStoreImpl, but that depends on how the datastore is saved previously